# jquery multiple selector with common tag name

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way by which you can use multiple selectors with common tag name.

So like, here i have `$('span.clone1, span.clone2, span.clone3')`

i just want to make it common.

Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you want here.

Comment: can you please explicitly state your question? I'm having a hard time figuring out what the problem is.

Comment: have edited my question sorry for the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
var myclasses = [ '.clone1', '.clone2', '.clone3', '.somethingelse' ];
$('span').filter( myclasses.join(',') );
$('input:text').filter( myclasses.join(',') );
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question something like this would work:

```
$("span[class^='clone']").blah()
```

Comment: they are at the same heirarchy levels.

Comment: if they are inputs then something like ... $("input[class^='clone']").blah()  assuming those class names are on the actual inputs

Comment: Here is jsfiddle is the structure similar to this? http://jsfiddle.net/ColdToast/WeraB/